# Parametrization of MDX query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have such query in MDX:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
  [Measures].[M1]
, [Measures].[M2]
, [Measures].[M3]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
  [DimensionName].[MemeberName].&[2008/1] 
} ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

How to parametrize this query in SSRS. I have tried:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
  [Measures].[M1]
, [Measures].[M2]
, [Measures].[M3]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
  [DimensionName].[MemeberName].&[@ParameterName] 
} ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

as well as

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
  [Measures].[M1]
, [Measures].[M2]
, [Measures].[M3]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
  [DimensionName].[MemeberName].&[=Parameters!ParameterName.Value] 
} ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

but as I can see in SQL Server profiler value of it is never set. Any ideas how to do it?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You have added a parameter to the report i guess?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
[Measures].[M1]
, [Measures].[M2]
, [Measures].[M3]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
STRTOMEMBER("[DimensionName].[MemeberName].&[" + @ParameterName + "]")
} ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: Syntax is very slightly off, the @parametername should be inside the brackets, and you're assuming he's surrounding it with square brackets already. Example: strtomember("[Dim date].[Month].&[" + CSTR(NOW()) +"]")